# WPTouch - how to remove shortcodes or make shortcodes function

Tags: plugins, shortcode, mobile

So as the title states - using WPTouch Mobile plugin (NOT Pro) I either want to make the shortcodes work as they should or remove them altoghether.

Currently they render on the page as `[shortcode]` which is no good.

I am good with a hack or any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean you want to make your own short codes work on the mobile theme?

This is possible, try the wptouch admin panel options to enable your plugins.

You can also copy your short code to the functions.php file in the wp touch theme folder.

Finally ... You may have to get the pro version of wptouch so you can develop the shortcode support.

Answer (score 1):

As Damian said, you can get them to work by adding the required code to the functions.php in the WPtouch themes folder. You just need to copy the shortcodes code from your main theme functions.php.

Just remember that your changes to the plugin will get blown away when the plugin updates. You can just make the changes again after the update.

You can find a full write-up at: http://tuxtweaks.com/2013/05/wptouch-enable-shortcodes/